# How to search and install the appropriate package of a software in RHEL distro?

Tags: linux, devops, redhat

I'll like to know how can I reach the software's package, so I'll know what to install with yum. For example, if I need to use the `nslookup` **command**, I need to install the `bind-utils` **package**.

Is there a way to find by myself what package needs to be installed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yum whatprovides
```

check the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html) for yum:

> Provides Command
> Command: provides
> Aliases: prov, whatprovides, wp

```
   dnf [options] provides <provide-spec>
          Finds the packages providing the given <provide-spec>.
          This is useful when one knows a filename and wants to find
          what package (installed or not) provides this file.  The
          <provide-spec> is gradually looked for at following
          locations:

          1. The <provide-spec> is matched with all file provides of
             any available package:

                $ dnf provides /usr/bin/gzip
                gzip-1.9-9.fc29.x86_64 : The GNU data compression program
                Matched from:
                Filename    : /usr/bin/gzip

          2. Then all provides of all available packages are
             searched:

                $ dnf provides "gzip(x86-64)"
                gzip-1.9-9.fc29.x86_64 : The GNU data compression program
                Matched from:
                Provide     : gzip(x86-64) = 1.9-9.fc29

          3. DNF assumes that the <provide-spec> is a system
             command, prepends it with /usr/bin/, /usr/sbin/
             prefixes (one at a time) and does the file provides
             search again. For legacy reasons (packages that didn’t
             do UsrMove) also /bin and /sbin prefixes are being
             searched:

                $ dnf provides zless
                gzip-1.9-9.fc29.x86_64 : The GNU data compression program
                Matched from:
                Filename    : /usr/bin/zless

          4. If this last step also fails, DNF returns “Error: No
             Matches found”.

          This command by default does not force a sync of expired
          metadata. See also Metadata Synchronization.
```

Comment: ```yum whatprovides``` finds the package's name of my existing programs that are already been installed. 

I'm talking about situations in that I don't have the programs on my *bin/ dir

Comment: read the man page again.

Comment: Alright! I can see that it does that and finally I've succeeded to work with that. At first, it didn't work. Don't know why, actually. Thank you so much!